# How to give dialog box error if user enters random letters JOptionPane

Tags: java, dialog, joptionpane

So i am new to java, and i am trying to use try and catch. For example if i ask how many grapes the user has, and they type bunches of letters, it will show a error dialog, instead of just getting a system error. I was able to do it with a scanner, but not with JOptionPane. I really want a dialog box to appear, that's why i am trying to use JOptionPane.showInputDialog.

Scanner which works...=

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class test {
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("How many grapes do u have?");
        int grapes = 1;
        try
        {
            grapes = input.nextInt();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Good job Sherlock you broke the program");
            return;
        }
        int mg;

        if (grapes >= 100)
            mg = 1;

        else
            mg = 2;

        switch (mg){
            case 1: System.out.println("You got a lot of grapes");
                break;
            case 2: System.out.println("You brarely got any grapes");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

JOptionPane which doesn't work...

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class bday
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String age = "0";
        try
        {
            age = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What was your age yesterday?");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thanks a lot, you broke it. CYA later.");
            return;
        }
        int iage = Integer.parseInt(age);

        String bday = "0";

         try
         {
             bday = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Was yesterday your B-Day? (True or False)");
         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "WHY U MESS UP PROGRAM???.... BYE BYE!!");
            return;
         }
         boolean bage = Boolean.parseBoolean(bday);
        if (bage == true){
            iage += 1;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are now " + iage);
        }
        else if (bage == false){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Happy unbirthday!");
        }
        if (iage ==10){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Congrats, double digits!");
        }
        if (iage >19){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "U aint a Teenager");
        }
        else if (iage < 13)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "U aint a Teenager");          

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're try/catching the wrong thing. You should place the parse statements in the try block since that is what throws the exception.

e.g., not

```
    String age = "0";
    try
    {
        age = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What was your age yesterday?");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thanks a lot, you broke it. CYA later.");
        return;
    }
    int iage = Integer.parseInt(age);
```

but rather:

```
String age = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What was your age yesterday?");
try {
  iage = Integer.parseInt(age);
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
  // show error
}
```

Also, you should avoid catching `Exception` but rather should only catch specific exceptions, here `NumberFormatException`.

---

**Edit**
In comment you ask:

> One more question, should i do the same with the boolean?

The boolean type is a bit trickier (in my mind) when it comes to parsing. To see how the `Boolean.parseBoolean(...)` works, please have a look at the [Boolean API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html), specifically the parseBoolean method. You'll see that it does not throw a NumberFormatException if the text entered does not make sense. The API will tell you what in fact *is* returned. A try/catch block won't work here. Consider using String's `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` if you need to trap for errors.

Comment: Never mind, i think i know what you mean. I will try that. Thanks for answering.

Comment: @user2593789: declare it first before using it.

Comment: It works, my problem was i tried to assign the variable twice. THANKS SOOOO MUCH!!!!

Comment: One more question, should i do the same with the boolean?

Comment: any idea what i should make the code. Or should i just ditch the boolean and assign true to 1 and false to 2 and do what you did above?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the line where it fails. I suspect it is `boolean bage = Boolean.parseBoolean(bday);`.
You are free to save anything in a String, but the conversion of "whatever" to a Boolean can fail.

Put it in your try/catch.